# Why copy a plist from the resources to document?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, directory, plist

This is what is my understanding: the resources in the project folder are read only. So, almost all examples show copying a plist from the resources to the app's document folder. Why can we not simply find the app's document folder (after first run) and create the initial plist there (i.e. in the documents folder of the app so that subsequently we can modify the plist via code?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: Yes, you can create an initial plist there. But before you do this, consider using `NSUserDefaults` to save the settings.

Comment: Thanks. Now I will have to explore the NSUserDefaults jungle out there. Anyway, if I changed it (assuming that I succeed), would it be set for all subsequent apps, or would be temporary only for this app? Thanks in advance!

Comment: NSUserDefaults is for your app only. Does not share across multiple apps.

Answer (score 1):

Because there might already be data needed in a plist when the app is first installed; and that data has to come from somewhere.  Why not from a plist?

Comment: Can it not come from the plist in the documents?

Comment: The Documents folder is created empty when an app bundle is first installed.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest using the Library folder rather than the Documents folder, just in case you do file sharing via iTunes at some stage. The Documents folder is available to the end user, whereas the Library folder is not.

Comment: I read somewhere that the Library folder is supposed to contain only application specific settings, and not to be used for files (like a plist). Would it be also read/write? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can put any files in the Library folder. I only put this warning, because I noobishly put all my version 1 system files in Documents, and then realised that users had access to them all, so the version 2 update had to move everything to the Library folder.

Comment: However, for settings, NSUserDefaults is the better idea.